# Modify arguments in scale_fill_gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using "scale_fill_gradient" to draw figures with ggplot2. Any of you know if we can modify arguments in (). For example:

```
scale_fill_gradient(low="red",high="grey")
```

Then I would like to modify as

```
scale_fill_gradient(-0.03="red",1.07="grey")
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a duplicate, but

```
scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "grey", limits = c(-0.03, 1.07)
```

should do the job. This is shown in the second example of the documentation of `scale_fill_gradient`. Please read the documentation.